# Helm-mode-dired-do-rename change name of file to a prefix of itself

Tags: helm, dired

Say I have a file named `foo` in directory `bar`. I also have `helm-mode` enabled and am trying to rename `foo` to `fo` through `dired`. Rename here ends up opening `helm-mode-dired-do-rename` and on typing `fo`, the only `helm` candidate is `foo`. How do I tell `helm` that the name I want to use is `fo`?

Comment: You issue seems to be similar to [this one](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/61). Try pressing `C-<backspace>` to disable automatic completion  and then type in the new name. (Let me know if this works: I don't have the time to test this myself right now.)

Comment: @Constantine No, that doesn't work. The word I am typing doesn't get auto-expanded. However, as long as `helm` finds a match for my input, pressing `RET` ends up selecting that match, instead of using my input as is.

Comment: @Constantine `C-c ?` in that helm window says "autoupdate may keep updating to an existent directory preventing you from creating a new directory. In this case, just hit C-<backspace> and then <backspace>. This should not be needed when copying/renaming files because autoupdate is disabled by default in this case."

Comment: I use `C-c <backspace>` to disable auto-expansion in Helm. 

I use Emacs mainly in console mode within tmux sessions.

Comment: @rimero auto-expansion is already disabled. When I type either `C-c <backspace>` or `C-<backspace>` it says `[Auto expansion enabled]` and I need to toggle it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select `foo` <kbd>R</kbd>, enter the new name (`fo` in this case) and <kbd>C-p</kbd> (to select `[?]fo` candidate) <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: <facepalm> Can't believe I didn't try this :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a name in helm selection using C-f (forward) and C-b (backward) for chars, C-left and C-right to the begin or end of words.